# remove numbers expressed in different ways before a key word

Tags: python, regex

I've attempting to clean numbers at the beginning of string and followed by a key word. This number can be expressed as `digit` (1 2 3), `ordinal number` (1st 2nd 3rd) or `strings` (one two three).

The idea is to keep the all the numbers immediately before a key word. Suppose the key words are `basic|main|foundation`. For instance, the following numbers are kept because they are followed by the key word `basic`:

```
'one two three basic', '1 2 3 basic', '1st 2nd 3rd basic'
```

On the other hand, setting a word in front of key word needs the removal of the numbers. For instance, the following numbers are gone because they are followed by `very` not a key word:

```
'one two three very basic', '1 2 3 very basic', '1st 2nd 3rd very basic'
```

These are the input example:

```
text=['one two three basic', '1 2 3 basic', '1st 2nd 3rd basic',
      'one two three very basic', '1 2 3 very basic', '1st 2nd 3rd very basic']
```

These are the expected strings:

```
expected=['one two three basic', '1 2 3 basic', '1st 2nd 3rd basic',
          'very basic', 'very basic', 'very basic']
```

I've tried this so far without desired results:

```
import re

text=['one two three basic', '1 2 3 basic', '1st 2nd 3rd basic',
      'one two three very basic', '1 2 3 very basic', '1st 2nd 3rd very basic']

for element in text:
    element = re.sub(
                 r'(^((?:\d+(?:(st|[rd]d|th))?\s+)+|(?:(one|two|three)+\s+)+))(?!(?:(basic|main|foundations)$))',
                 '',
                 element,
                 0,
                 re.IGNORECASE)

    print(element)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The examples seem oversimplified. What about `five hundred thousand two hundred and forty-eight very basic`?

Comment: I will get those from a list, so in the main list those numbers will be included (one|two|three...|one thousand|two thousand|one hundred|two hundred|three hundred|forty|forty-one|forty-two). Any number has to go in the second section: `(?:(one|two|three)+\s+)`

Comment: so as long as the number expressed as string is in the list, do not have any problem, this can be just three numbers `one|two|three`

Comment: Here is one way of doing it - https://ideone.com/1b95Mr

Comment: After looking at your code it appears the following should be a match: `"1rd 2st 3nd basic`"` (even though `1rd` should be `1st`, etc.). Is that your intent? If you plan to extend this, as you indicate in your first comment above, how would you deal with meaningless strings such as `"five thousand three thousand"` or `"one hundred twenty-two thirty-four"`? That certainly can be dealt with but I think you'd be better off relying more on code and less on gigantic regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using

```
import re

text=['one two three basic', '1 2 3 basic', '1st 2nd 3rd basic',
      'one two three very basic', '1 2 3 very basic', '1st 2nd 3rd very basic']
num_list=['one','two','three']
keywords = ['basic','main','foundations']
dgt_part = r'\d+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?'
num_wrd_part = '(?:{})'.format( '|'.join(num_list) )
kwd_part = '|'.join(keywords)
rx = re.compile(r'\b(?=({0}(?:\s+{0})*|{1}(?:\s+{1})*))\1(?!\s+(?:{2})\b)\s*'.format(dgt_part, num_wrd_part, kwd_part), re.I)
print(rx.pattern)
for element in text:
    print( rx.sub('',  element) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/w3BIz6)

Output:

```
one two three basic
1 2 3 basic
1st 2nd 3rd basic
very basic
very basic
very basic
```

The resulting regex will look like `\b(?=(\d+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?(?:\s+\d+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?)*|(?:one|two|three)(?:\s+(?:one|two|three))*))\1(?!\s+(?:basic|main|foundations)\b)\s*`, see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/OpOJRH/1). The main points are:

- The pattern is made of parts dynamically
- The capturing group in the lookahead and the subsequent backreference are used to emulate atomic group behavior (these are not supported by Python `re`)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=(\d+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?(?:\s+\d+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?)*|(?:one|two|three)(?:\s+(?:one|two|three))*))` - a positive lookahead that captures

  - `\d+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?(?:\s+\d+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?)*` - digit number followed with 0 or more repetitions of 1+ whitespace separated digit numbers
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:one|two|three)(?:\s+(?:one|two|three))*` - word number followed with 0 or more repetitions of 1+ whitespace separated word numbers
- `\1` - the value captured in Group 1
- `(?!\s+(?:basic|main|foundations)\b)` - fail the match if there are 0+ whitespaces and one of the keywords as a whole word
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Comment: This appears to match `1rd 2st 3nd`  in `1rd 2st 3nd very basic`. That may not be a problem but it should be understood it could occur.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is exactly what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

With assumptions I will list below you could use the regex:

```
\b(?:one two three|1 2 3|1st 2nd 3rd)\s+basic\b|(?<=\bone two three\s)\w+\s+basic\b|(?<=\b1 2 3 )\w+\s+basic\b|(?<=\b1st 2nd 3rd )\w+\s+basic\b
```

which contains no capture groups.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FZdmYt/2/)

The assumptions are as follows:

- One of the literals `'one two three'`, `'1 2 3'` or `1st 2nd 3rd'` is to be matched;
- one of the three literals above may be preceded by other characters;
- if one of the three literals is followed by one or more spaces followed by the word `'basic'`, possibly followed by other characters, the string comprised of the three literals, space(s) and `'basic'` is matched; and
- the word preceding `'basic'` followed by one or more spaces followed by `'break'` is matched if one of the three literals above is immediately followed by one space, the word preceding `'break'` followed by one or more spaces, followed by `'break'`.

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\b                    # match word break
(?:                   # begin non-cap grp
  one two three       # match string
  |                   # or
  1 2 3               # match string
  |                   # or
  1st 2nd 3rd         # match string
)                     # end non-cap grp                    
\s+                   # match 1+ spaces 
basic                 # match string
\b                    # match word break
|                     # or
(?<=\bone two three ) # match string in positive look-behind
\w+\s+                # match word, then 1+ spaces 
basic                 # match string
\b                    # match word break 
|                     # or
(?<=\b1 2 3 )         # match string in positive look-behind
\w+\s+                # match word, then 1+ spaces 
basic                 # match string
\b                    # match word break 
|                     # or
(?<=\b1st 2nd 3rd )   # match string in positive look-behind
\w+\s+                # match word, then 1+ spaces 
basic                 # match string
\b                    # match word break
```

The regex could be simplified somewhat if certain other regex engines could be used, due in part to the fact that Python's engine evidently does not support PCRE's `\K` (roughly, "forget everthing matched so far") or look-behinds of the form `(?<=a|bb)`, even though the alternation involves two fixed-length strings. (Python evidently requires them to be the same length as well.)